# passing parameters from callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Basically I need to pass a parameter as result from one callback to another callback.
Here is the code:

```
var main = io
  .of('')
  .on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('joinDynNs',function(data,join_cb){
        var myBoard=0;
        routeToBoard("alex", "123", function(id) {
      myBoard=id;
      });
      var dyn_ns = io.of('/' + myBoard)
                       .on('connection', function(ns_socket){console.log('user connected to ' + myBoard);});
                       join_cb({namespace:myBoard});  
    });
  });
```

My problem is I cannot pass the "id" from routeToBoard to myBoard variable. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

My routeToBoard function is:

```
function routeToBoard(userId, passw, cb) {
    var boardId = 0;
    var nStore = require('nstore/lib/nstore').extend(require('nstore/lib/nstore/query')());
    var users = nStore.new('data/users.db', function() {
        users.find({
            user: userId,
            pass: passw
        }, function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                boardId = -1;
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                boardId = results.digitboard.board;
            }
            cb(boardId);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Where is your route to board function ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling new function at `myBoard=id` line, like `parseNewId(id);` and put there your next logic. <strike>This is because `var dyn_ns...` is executed just after `socket.on(...)`  is initialized, not after it's finished. So myBoard is not there yet.</strike>
Sorry, I've missed parentheses... But still you need to move your after-id-get logic inside that `routeToBoard` function.

**EDIT**

The 'idea':

```
var res = document.getElementById("res");

res.innerHTML +="<br/>Init";
ioOn('connection', function (socket) {
      res.innerHTML +="<br/>ioOn callback";
      socketOn('joinDynNs', function (data, join_cb) {
          res.innerHTML +="<br/>socketOn callback";
          var myBoard = 111;

          routeToBoard("alex", "123", function (id) {
                                            res.innerHTML +="<br/>routeToBoard callback";
                                            myBoard = id;
                                            //var dyn_ns = io.of('/' + myBoard).on('connection', function (ns_socket) { console.log('user connected to ' + myBoard); });
                                        });
          join_cb({ namespace: myBoard });
      });
  });

 function delayMe()
 {
    var c=0
    for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        c += i*Math.random();
 }

function ioOn(string, callback)
{
    res.innerHTML +="<br/>ioOn body";
     delayMe();
    callback("socket");
}
function socketOn(string, callback)
{
    res.innerHTML +="<br/>socketOn body";
    delayMe();
    callback("data",function(obj){alert("3"+" obj.namespace: " + obj.namespace)});
}
function routeToBoard(userId, passw, cb) {
    res.innerHTML +="<br/>routeToBoard body";
    delayMe();
    var boardId = 0;
    var users = fkc1('data/users.db', function(){
        res.innerHTML +="<br/>fkc1 callback";
        usersFind({
            user: userId,
            pass: passw
        },  function(err, results) {
                res.innerHTML +="<br/>userFind callback";
                cb(666);
            });
    });
}
function fkc1(string,callback)
{
    res.innerHTML +="<br/>fkc1 body";
    delayMe();
    callback();//no params callback
}

function usersFind(credentials,callback)
{
    res.innerHTML +="<br/>userFind body";
    delayMe();
    callback("er","result");
}
```

I don't think it's useful. Just the major idea to check if all variables are passed well. Unfortunately I don't know this node.js library, but the concept isn't new to me.

Put also `<div id="res" ></div>` into body section to see results...

Comment: yes, but my problem is I have another functions who needs the boardId param, and when I try to put var dyn_ns = io.of('/' + myBoard)
                       .on('connection', function(ns_socket){console.log('user connected to ' + myBoard);});
      join_cb({namespace:myBoard}); into routeToBoard function it doesn't work....

Comment: You can still call these function from inside `routeToBoard` function, where you already get id; or, if these function are not sequential, store ID in value accessible by all functions.

Comment: I have just prepared simpler version of your code, it works fine, but I don't have any latency and I assume you have. Probably you have to check that node.js library documentation for more info.